# Solr: Query runtime faceting calculations on date fields and current date

Tags: solr, solr4, faceted-search, facet

Given the following schema fields:

```
<field indexed="true" stored="true" name="Status" type="int" />
<field indexed="true" stored="true" name="StatusDate1" type="tdate" />
<field indexed="true" stored="true" name="StatusDate2" type="tdate" />
```

Is it possible for solr to handle a calculation of Status, given the current daily date and the fields StatusDate1 and StatusDate2?

For example: A certain object contains (ignore sintax) StatusDate1: 1/9/2016, StatusDate2: 5/9/2016, knowing that today is the 9/9/2016 the expected output would be Status=2.

This Status is calculated based on the current date and the StatusDate fields of every object. I would like to **facet** the Status field.

Is **function queries** the way to go? Or do I need to handle this at index time? (A task indexing every day would seem dummy) What is the best way to tackle this issue?

Note: **My solr version is 4.6.0**

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of faceting, have you tried the [**stats** component](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component)?
stats=true&stats.field=Status... filtering by the date fields??

Comment: Thanks for the comment Nuno! And long time no see by the way, faceting is really what I need to evaluate if solr can give me in this scenario. I can actually make the querying work with some 'tricks', but had no luck with faceting.

Comment: Totally understand it! But regard that the stats component also works with facets! Not trying to put in that direction, just putting the option in front of you